# How to select all edges/vertex between 2

Tags: selection-tools

something selecting edges is very time consuming and you dont want to user the shoertcut to select everything just a small part connected by 2 edges.

how to accomplish that, meaning, I select an edge at one end and another at another end an automatically select everything between?

thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using 'Alt + Right-Click' will select everything in a loop of vertices. I'm not sure whether you can select 2 vertices and everything in-between, but another alternative would be using 'Alt-B' to view a filtered down part of the model?

Comment: Note for 2.8+ users, it is now 'Alt + Left-Click' by default as the default selection mouse button has changed